# Update profile information - Calling Update profile information on Meta Stack Exchange profile does not get dynamic anchor links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, stack-exchange

When navigating to your own network profile and selecting *Update profile info* from a profile which has formatting i.e. links, it doesn't seem the formatting is copied over to the Stack Exchange profile.

I imagine the generic Stack Exchange profile is different from Meta.StackExchange where Meta is an actual community, so it has its own profile. I'm not sure if this is expected? I am filing a bug anyway, but feel free to close if this is expected.

Stack Overflow Profile:

[image]

Stack Exchange Profile:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for marking as dupe sorry about that @Shog9!